# Make mysql output rows terminated by other character (e.g. crlf) instead of default line feed into stdout

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen that Mysql can make output lines terminate by other character (e.g. '\r\n') instead of default '\n' when using SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement ([In official documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)),

```
SELECT column from table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But it can only output to a file.
Now I want make the output into **stdout** with lines terminate by  '\r\n' because my python program use pipe to get data from mysql commandline client.

Is there any equivalent way?

Comment: mysql does not communicate with stdout, that's for the client application (e.g. mysql command line client) to take care of. So, you need to make the cli tool to export the data in a way that's expected bu your program or use one of the python mysql clients to connect directly from python to mysql.

Comment: Well, probably you cannot make the mysql cli client change its output, so either you change your python script to work with \n line separators or use a python mysql connector instead of cli.